# Big picture in counting complexities

Tags: complexity-classes, counting-complexity

**(1)** Is there a relation ( conjectured relation) between $\mathsf{\#P}$ and $\mathsf{CH}$?

**(2)** How does $\tau$ conjecture in complexity of factorial fit in the picture?

Is there a good reference?

$\mathsf{CH}$ is counting hierarchy and $\mathsf\tau$ conjecture essentially conjectures a lower bound of $\omega(\log^cn)$ for any fixed $c>0$ on number of $\{+,-,\times\}$ operations needed for $n!$ computation.

(I searched on answers in ctheory but was unsuccessful)

Comment: what is CH ? and what is $\tau$ ?

Comment: @SureshVenkat $\mathsf{CH}$ is counting hierarchy and $\mathsf\tau$ conjecture essentially conjectures a lower bound on number of $\{+,-,\times\}$ operations needed for $n!$ computation.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference for the "$\tau$"-conjecture?

Comment: @HuckBennett What I gave is not an exact form (but $n!$ computation is sufficienct to show difficulty) refer http://www.automata.rwth-aachen.de/stacs07/slides/Buergisser.pdf.

Comment: I don't understand question (1). $\mathsf{\#P}$ is contained in $\mathsf{CH}$ by definition, and the containment is conjectued to be proper. What other relation are you thinking about?

Comment: @JanJohannsen If you look at the slides in the comment it is mentioned $\mathsf{CH}$ and $\mathsf{\#P}$ are related like $\mathsf{PH}$ and $\mathsf{P}$

Comment: Yes, so then what is the question in (1)?

Comment: @JanJohannsen If you look 'closely' at the slides in the comment it is mentioned CH and #P are related like PH and P but he does not give a clue on what this is